# Whta does '\+::::::/bin/bash' in /etc/passwd mean?

Tags: users, nis, nsswitch

Found the line `\+::::::/bin/bash` in my /etc/passwd, which looks strange to me. What does that mean? Has my computer been hacked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer lies in the [`nsswitch.conf(5)`](http://manual.cream.org/index.cgi/nsswitch.conf.5#2) man page:

> #### Interaction with +/- syntax (compat mode)
>
> Linux libc5 without NYS does not have the name service switch but does allow the user some policy control. In `/etc/passwd` you could have entries of the form `+user` or `+@netgroup` (include the specified user from the NIS passwd map), `-user` or `-@netgroup` (exclude the specified user), and `+` (include every user, except the excluded ones, from the NIS passwd map).
>
> You can override certain passwd fields for a particular user from the NIS passwd map by using the extended form of `+user::::::` in /etc/passwd. Non-empty fields override information in the NIS passwd map.
>
> Since most people only put a `+` at the end of /etc/passwd to include everything from NIS, the switch provides a faster alternative for this case (`passwd: files nis`) which doesn’t require the single `+` entry in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`, and `/etc/shadow`. If this is not sufficient, the NSS `compat` service provides full +/- semantics. By default, the source is `nis`, but this may be overridden by specifying `nisplus` as source for the pseudo-databases `passwd_compat`, `group_compat` and `shadow_compat`. These pseudo-databases are only available in GNU C Library.

Assuming that your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains `passwd: compat`, I believe that that line means "include all NIS users, but override the login shell to `/bin/bash`".